# UV Rectangle projected wrong way

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I have an image that is a rectangle shape, and have created a box that is the same proportions. After creating the box I reset the scale back to 1,1,1. When I try to map the image to the top of the box (the side that is the same size/proportions as the image), it gets mapped the wrong direction. The long edge of the image is lined up and squished to to short edge of the box and visa versa. I cannot find any way to rotate or otherwise make it project correctly.

Here's what happens no matter what method I use. I have even turned every edge into a seam and tried just unwrapping the top faces.

[image]

Comment: Just put the mouse cursor in the uv map editor and then type r90 and hit Enter. If it's upside down then r180 and Enter.

Comment: Also, go into the UVs menu of the UV editor and turn on Constrain to Image Bounds.